# Polymer social-icons not working on a submenu

Tags: icons, polymer, material-design

I'm trying to do a Submenu with icons, and some of them are from the social-icons set, but I don't know why the don't show. here is my code, maybe i missed something.

```
<script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">    
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-menu/core-submenu.html">      
<link href="../bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html" rel="import">
<link href="../bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html" rel="import">    
<link href="../bower_components/core-icons/editor-icons.html" rel="import">
<link href="../bower_components/core-icons/social-icons.html" rel="import">    
<link href="../bower_components/core-icons/hardware-icons.html" rel="import">

<core-menu> 
    <core-submenu icon="cloud" label="Accounts">
       <core-item id="used_quota" icon="hardware:memory" label="Used quota" class="menu_item core-selected" horizontal="" center="" layout=""></core-item>
       <core-item id="disabled_accounts" class="menu_item" icon="remove-circle" label="Disabled accounts" horizontal="" center="" layout=""></core-item>
       <core-item id="used_licenses" class="menu_item" icon="verified-user" label="Used Licenses" horizontal="" center="" layout=""></core-item>
       <core-item id="suspended_accounts" icon="report" label="Suspended accounts" class="menu_item" horizontal="" center="" layout=""></core-item>     
    </core-submenu>

    <core-submenu icon="today" label="Calendar">        
    </core-submenu>

    <core-submenu icon="insert-drive-file" label="Docs">        
    </core-submenu>

    <core-submenu icon="mail" label="Gmail"> 
       <core-item id="emails_exchanged" icon="send" label="Emails exchanged" class="menu_item" horizontal="" center="" layout=""></core-item>
       <core-item id="emails_received" icon="inbox" label="Emails received"  class="menu_item" horizontal="" center="" layout=""></core-item>
    </core-submenu>

    <core-submenu icon="social-icons:plus-one" label="Google +"> 
    </core-submenu>

    <core-submenu icon="phone-android" label="Mobile"> 
    </core-submenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the error. The icon-set was mistaken, the correct is just "social" not "social-icons"

```
<core-submenu icon="social:plus-one" label="Google +"></core-submenu>
```